# DvaJS - Load saved state from localStorage into state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dvajs

I initiate my `dvajs` app like below. Where I store state into localStorage with `onStateChange` hook. Saving states into `localstorage` works just fine.

```
const app = dva({
    history: createBrowserHistory(),
    defaultState: getPersistedState(),
    onError(e) {
        message.error(e.message, /* duration */3);
    },
    onStateChange(state){
        window.localStorage.setItem('adligence', JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log('state changed', state);
    }
});
```

Now when the page refreshes I want to load saved state into the app. so I wrote `getPersistedState()` and loading persisted state into `defaultState`. Which loads fine at initial load.

But the problem is when models setup states props are replaced by the models' default data. For example here is one of my model definition.

```
export default {

    namespace: 'training',

    state: {
        videos: [],
        current: {}
    }, ....
    ....
```

All loaded initial persisted data will be replaced by this model. So, how do I load the `localstorage` value into the state correctly so it stays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `initialState` instead of `defaultState` on dva options. And for models set `state` to `null` and if you want to add any default props use `initialState` as well.

### Modified Code

**Dva Init**

```
const app = dva({
    history: createBrowserHistory(),
    initialState: getPersistedState(),
    onError(e) {
        message.error(e.message, /* duration */3);
    },
    onStateChange(state){
        window.localStorage.setItem('adligence', JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log('state changed', state);
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
export default {

    namespace: 'training',

    initialState: {
        videos: [],
        current: {}
    },
    state: null
     ....
    ....
```